# Update a single vhost file using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have the following file: `roles/homepage/templates/vhost_443.conf.j2`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName {{ vhost_name }}
    {% if vhost_aliases is defined %}
    {% for vhost_alias in vhost_aliases %}
    ServerAlias {{ vhost_alias }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    ServerAdmin webmaster@extension.org
    DocumentRoot {{ vhost_document_root }}
    ErrorLog {{ vhost_log_dir }}/error.log
    CustomLog  {{ vhost_log_dir }}/access.log combined
    LogLevel info ssl:warn
    # LogLevel alert rewrite:t
    ...
```

This file is referenced in `roles/homepage/tasks/main.yml`

```
...
- name: create ssl vhost
  template:
    src: vhost_443.conf.j2
    dest: "/etc/apache2/sites-available/{{ vhost_name }}_443.conf"
  notify: restart apache
  tags:
    - vhostconfig
  ...
```

Is there a way to run just this portion (task?) in `roles/homepage/tasks/main.yml` so I am only updating the vhost_443.conf file on the server without running all the other tasks in main.yml, or should I create a task just to update this file?

I was considering running:
`ansible-playbook roles/homepage/tasks/main.yml` but this would run all the other commands in main.yml.

Comment: I notice you have `tags:` on that task; did `ansible-playbook --tags vhostconfig ...` not do what you wanted?

Comment: There are many dozen tasks with that tag, so I am guessing running the command you shared would run/update all of those files on various servers.

Comment: Wonder if I could add another tag to this task...something like update_homepage_vhost then run `ansible-playbook --tags update_homepage_vhost`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up going with was to add a tag `update_vhost` to the specific task I wanted to run in `roles/homepage/tasks/main.yml`. So in the

```
...
- name: create ssl vhost
  template:
    src: vhost_443.conf.j2
    dest: "/etc/apache2/sites-available/{{ vhost_name }}_443.conf"
  notify: restart apache
  tags: ['vhostconfig', 'update_vhost']
  ...
```

Now when I want to run that specific task I run `ansible-playbook playbooks/webapps/homepage.yml --tags "update_vhost"` to run that task only.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep roles/homepage/tasks/main.yml as one file, then you may want to separate the logic into blocks.  Create a variable **homepage-run**

If you want to run the whole role, set homepage-run: full

If you want to run the vhost update, set homepage-run: vhost

```
- block:
  - name: Run homepage setup part 1
    - task1
    - task2
    - task3
  when: homepage-run == "full"

- block:
  - name: Run vhost setup
    - name: create ssl vhost
      template:
        src: vhost_443.conf.j2
        dest: "/etc/apache2/sites-available/{{ vhost_name }}_443.conf"
      notify: restart apache
      tags:
        - vhostconfig
  when: ( homepage-run == "full" ) or ( homepage-run == "vhost" )

- block:
  - name: Run homepage setup part 2
    - task1
    - task2
    - task3
  when: homepage-run == "full"
```

Comment: ..and whats the command to run this? ansible-playbook --homepage-run full roles/homepage/tasks/main.yml? Spoiler alert...this does not work.

Comment: I think I am approaching this wrong. I am getting an error that this is not a playbook. Do I need to create an associated playbook to run this?

Comment: How are you running roles/homepage/tasks/main.yml?  Is that a role called in a playbook, or are you running it by itself with the ansible-playbook command?